# Fix Blank Icons in Dock Stacks and Grids

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, dock, ui

I use Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6.8), and here's my problem: Stack and grid views of folders very often look like this:

[image: missing images]

These empty boxes are not very useful for finding files quickly. When I open a such a view, I notice high processor usage by processes

```
QTKitServer
diskimages-helper
```

I assume that they are busy with loading/generating icons and previews for my files. These processes often use the CPU for minutes, but very few icons are generated. Icon and preview generation never seems to get finished for a folder. Does anyone else experience this? Is there a way to fix or speed up this process?

Comment: I'm also experiencing this, on Lion and Mountain Lion. I tried removing and re-adding the folder in question, but that only partially resolves the issue — some icons get restored, but not all.

Comment: Does Quick Look work fine in other places such as Finder?

Comment: Meanwhile, Mountain Lion came out and I upgraded, so I don't have this issue any more.

Comment: Closely related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129005/how-to-fix-blank-icons-for-download-and-documents-stacks-in-the-dock

Comment: I am having that same problem on Sierra.