# How to fix blank icons for Download and Documents stacks in the Dock

Tags: macos, finder, dock

I'm getting blank icons for stacks (e.g. Downloads) and grids (e.g. Documents) in the Dock. Nothing seems to fix it. Have tried relaunching the Finder and even a full reboot, but nothing helps. Any ideas?

There's a [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50023/fix-blank-icons-in-dock-stacks-and-grids) about exactly the same problem from a while back but that's no help as the OP said that upgrading to Mountain Lion fixed his problem.

I'm running Mavericks (10.9.2). Problem started recently, but I can't tie it definitely to the 10.9.2 update.

UPDATE: tried restarting the Dock and that got back 2 or 3 icons, nothing more.

Here's an example of the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing PDFs from the stack's contents. <sub>[Source](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=13878907&postcount=3)</sub>

If that doesn't work, try backing up and removing `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist` and relaunching the Dock (`killall -HUP Dock`).

Comment: Turned out it was a complex Excel spreadsheet in the Downloads folder that was causing the problem. Following the advice in the thread you linked to, the icons *would* appear if I left the stack open for long enough. Once I removed the .xls file, it all went back to normal.
My guess is that Dock (or Finder) is taking too long trying to render a miniature version of the file. As you pointed out, this can happen with PDFs too.

Comment: Removing the .plist worked for me. Great answer, even three years later +1. I only wish thhat I had taken a screenshot of my dock prior, because it reset the applications on it.